# Why does Android SoundManager sometimes play sounds twice?

Tags: android

I have app in which I used soundmanager with 26 sounds. It works fine in simulator but when I tried it in my Samsung Galaxy it played twice some of the sounds.

Does soundmanager have a limit?

Comment: Apparently there was a limit to his

Comment: 26 is a limit for soundpool?I am getting all sound played but some of sounds randomly played twice.

Comment: i have now used mediaplyer for that and it works fine

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547551/issue-with-soundpool-and-samsung-galaxy-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think SoundManager has a limit on the number of different sounds it can handle, and maybe some file types are not supported. Instead, I used MediaPlayer and it works without any problems.